Google Sheet Count if
I'm working on a serial number in google sheet
here's what i did
=Arrayformula(IF(F2:F="",,LEFT(F2:F,2))&  "-" & IF(E2:E="",,YEAR(E2:E) &  "-" & "0" &  MONTH(E2:E) & "-00" & COUNTIFS(E2:E, E2:E, ROW(E2:E), "<="&ROW(E2:E))))

And the result

all of  them counted as 001 because it counts the date, not the month
Here's the output that I want

is this possible? Sorry for my bad english.
another question,added the 2 dates 3/20 in the last 2 rows and the serial must be 001A and 001B. how can i do this?
enter image description here

Questions on SO should focus on one problem at the time. If you have another question, then please post another question...


You may try:
=Arrayformula(IF(F2:F="",,LEFT(F2:F,2))&  "-" & IF(E2:E="",,YEAR(E2:E) &  "-" &TEXT(MONTH(E2:E),"00") & "-00" & COUNTIFS(eomonth(E2:E,)&F2:F, eomonth(E2:E,)&F2:F, ROW(E2:E), "<="&ROW(E2:E))))


To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas (instead of winging it from screenshots), the recommended method is creating a markdown table. Use this table generator to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Another way is to share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker to ease the process of sharing
